# Selecting a particular drop down menu list item in Selenium web driver

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I'm trying to select a particular option from a select drop down list using .NET Selenium web driver (the options will then be posted as part of the form submission).

I'm currently trying the following (which works when I step through the code - i.e. the option seems to get selected in the web browser, but as soon as I execute the code for real the selecting of the option fails to work):

```
selectWebElement.Click();
selectWebElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[text() = '" + text + "']")).Click();
```

Do I need some sort of Wait in my code?  Does anyone know a bullet proof way of doing this?

**UPDATE:**

Since posting this I have learned that a more elegant way to set the selected option by it's text is:

```
new SelectElement(selectWebElement).SelectByText(text);
```

However, this does not appear to fix the problem.  Another thing I did not mention before was that the form is actually inside an iFrame and I'm using the following to switch to it:

```
WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeElement);
```

Not sure if the fact its in an iframe would cause a problem but I can successfully get a reference to the select element.  (The form also has a number of text input elements that I can successfully get to and set etc.)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the HTML for these drop downs?

Comment: Which browser and browser version are you using? Which version of its web driver are you using?

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have those details. I asked the question over 7 years ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly click on the drop-down, just use webdriver API call as follows:

selectWebElement.selectByVisibleText("");

or

selectWebElement.selectByIndex();

or

selectWebElement.selectByValue("");

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will probably need to add a short wait between the steps as it takes a small period of time for the dropdown to animate and be fully displayed.  If the second click occurs too quickly this can cause a failure.

A simple fixed wait period of, say, one second should work.  You could explicitly wait for the animation to complete but in the simple case of dropdowns a short fixed wait should suffice.

Comment: Tried adding a Thread.Sleep() (even up to 3 seconds) after each click but this does not appear to be helping.

Comment: Theres no "error".  It's just not successfully setting the selected option.